# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b' (molfile_to_params.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, lambda, bioinformatics

I'm currently debugging a file called molfile_to_params.py which is module of PyRosetta, but I'm currently having a trouble with a line of code that i don't know how to debug. There are already two enteries about this but it doesn't do it for my case.

```
tmp_children.sort(key=(lambda a,b: cmp(a.is_H, b.is_H)))
```

The program gives the error that I already mention and show this line as the source of the problem. But this is not the original line.

```
tmp_children.sort(lambda a,b: cmp(a.is_H, b.is_H))
```

This was the original line and it gave the error: TypeError: sort() takes no positional arguments
So I added the "key =" which I saw in another entry.
I'm just a HS Sophmore so my Python knowledge is below par, so I would be thankful if the community can lend a hand on this.
Thank you!

Comment: What is `tmp_children`?

Comment: Whoever wrote that is wrong. `key` is a key function that takes a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `tmp_children` is a list then the `key` parameter of `.sort` gets only one item at a time.
What you are trying to use is the `cmp` parameter that was available in python 2 but not in python 3. try changing you code like this:

```
tmp_children.sort(key=lambda a: a.is_H)
```

you can read more about python sorting [here](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html)